# Can Worklight Studio 6.0 and Worklight Studio 6.1 be installed on the same machine

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have a laptop running Windows 7 Pro.  Is it safe to install both WL studio 6.0 and 6.1 on the same laptop?  If it is safe to have both versions installed can the Android SDKs be shared between the installs or should each version of WL studio have its own install of the Android SDKs.

Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily install multiple versions of WL studio on 1 machine, just use a fresh install of Eclipse for each version. Creating separate workspaces inside of eclipse will have the same version of WL across all workspaces so you will need multiple Eclipse instances to accomplish this. In regards to your Android SDK question you can point each eclipse instance to the same Android SDK, but you will need to install the android tools on each version in order to work properly.

Please make sure you are running the latest 6.0.0.x ifix when attempting to run at the same time as some issues were resolved in this version. If you are an IBM WL customer please request the latest fix pack containing this fix.

Answer (score 0):

Also, ensure you install the right version of Eclipse for each Worklight Studio version. Worklight 6.0 only runs on [eclipse 4.2.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2) (Juno SR2), while Worklight 6.1 runs on either eclipse 4.2.2 or [eclipse 4.3.1](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr1) (Kepler SR1). See [System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838) for detailed requirements for all Worklight versions.